# Rails - destroy associations from object with condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have an object `@foo` with a :has_many associations to `bar` and I want before `foo` is destroyed all association objects from `bar` will be destroyed too if the `bar` has the property `type = test`.

the following code is working and the `foo` object is deleted but the `bars` are still there:
(if I dont't use the condition `.where(type: "test)` all `bars` will be deleted)

```
  def destroy
    @foo.bars.each{|b| b.update_attribute(:blub_id, nil)}
    @foo.bars.where(type: "test").destroy_all
    @foo.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to foo_url, notice: 'Foo was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove `@foo.bars.each{|b| b.update_attribute(:blub_id, nil)}` and make another try. I supposed that `blub_id` is a foreign key that indicates to which foo the current bar belongs to.

When you make the `blub_id` is equal to null, the records with a `blub_id` null is belongs to nothing and then `@foo.bars.where(type: "test").destroy_all` doesn't include these bars.

Answer (score 3):

Don't know if that's a overall rule or just for that controller action, but I think would be better to do that on the model.

Don't know what exactly what the line

```
@foo.bars.each{|b| b.update_attribute(:blub_id, nil)}
```

does, but if blub_id is the foreign key, you should do that AFTER destroying the bars with test type.  On your foo model, you can do it like this:

```
before_destroy :destroy_test_bars

def destroy_test_bars
   self.bars.where(type: "test").destroy_all
   self.bars.update_all(blub_id: nil)
end
```

Then, on your controller, it would be just

```
  def destroy
    @foo.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to foo_url, notice: 'Foo was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end
```

Think it could work. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

One of the good way will be to add after_destroy callback where you can write any logic you want.

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :bars
  after_destroy :cleanup

  private
  def cleanup
    if self.bars.where(type: "test")
      self.bars.destroy_all
    end
  end
end
```